# Getting combinations of multilevel arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, combinations

```
a = [1,2,3,4].combination(3).to_a
```

returns

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

What do I need to do to get the following combination of the array shown below

```
[["1a","1b"],2,3,4]
```

should be

```
=> [["1a", 2, 3], ["1a", 2, 4], ["1a", 3, 4],["1b", 2, 3], ["1b", 2, 4], ["1b", 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

It is important that values from the second level **aren't** put in a combination together.

The array could also be

```
[["1a","1b","1c",...],2,3,4]
```

The values themselves are unique.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution below will flatten and product any combination of arrays and scalars:

```
a = [["1a","1b"],2,3,["4a","4b"]]

a.combination(a.size - 1).map do |e| 
  e.map { |scalar| [*scalar] } # convert scalars to arrays of size 1
end.map do |arrays| 
  arrays.reduce &:product      # reduce by vector/cartesian product
end.flat_map do |deeps| 
  deeps.map &:flatten          # flatten the result
end

#⇒ [
#      ["1a", 2, 3], ["1b", 2, 3], ["1a", 2, "4a"], ["1a", 2, "4b"],
#      ["1b", 2, "4a"], ["1b", 2, "4b"], ["1a", 3, "4a"], 
#      ["1a", 3, "4b"], ["1b", 3, "4a"], ["1b", 3, "4b"],
#      [2, 3, "4a"], [2, 3, "4b"]
#  ]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very nice! (5 more characters to go)

Comment: In fact, feel free to change a parameter, passed to `combination` from `2` upto initial array size: the code will still produce an expected result.

Comment: I did. I really learned a lot from this answer. Thanks again. Keep it up!

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [["1a","1b"],2,3,4]

head, tail = [a[0], a[1..-1]]

res = head.flat_map{|h| ([h] + tail).combination(3).to_a}.uniq
```

Comment: and I was about to post the same :)

Comment: Thanks! May be you could give me a hint how to do `[["1a","1b"],2,3,["4a","4b"]]` as well?

Comment: That's a bit harder, I think you'd have to scan the top-level array and separate out all array elements from all non-array elements, and if order matters you'd need to keep track of index as well. I don't know if there's a particularly clean solution though...

Comment: Ok, this is what I was afraid of :) Do you know where I can find the `head, tail` in the ruby docs? I will update this question when I'm done. You pushed me in the right direction. Thanks so far!

Comment: `head` and `tail` are variables here, not methods

Comment: On second thought, regarding "no clean solution", I think if you recursively expanded each sub-array into multiple flat top-level arrays and then just call `combination` on those, that would work quite nicely...

Comment: @user12341234 There is no need in recursion, everything might be done in `O(N)`, please see my answer below in case you are curious.